# redis node library json serialization for list values

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm trying to create an activity feed list in redis using the redis-node library and had a json serialization question.

If I lpush a value into a key, the values get stored as escaped json, and when I retrieve with lrange, I get a list of escaped json back.

Should I simply iterate over the list items and JSON.parse(item) each, or is there a better more efficient method?  Specifically, is there a configuration I can use to avoid the overhead of escaping and unescaping the json values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JSON.strinfigy(object)` when storing your value and use `JSON.parse(value)` when retrieving it.

Comment: is there a way to store it without the escaped quotes, or as a native json object rather than stringily and parse?

Comment: redis stores JSON as a string. Why does it matter if quotes in values are escaped? They have to be in order for anyone to know when the value ends.

Comment: was hoping to avoid iterating through the list item collection and calling json parse on each item.

Comment: If it did return a Javascript object instead of a JSON string, it would have to call `JSON.parse` on it at some point. You can extend the redis module by adding a middleware function that does just that.

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey Yes, I modified Douglas Crawfords [JSON](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) script.  It removes the unecessary quotes around the key names (but still leaves the quotes around the property names (obviously or JSON wouldn't work :)).  Here is the [script](http://pastebin.com/dZ6iVwCP), and use `JSONLITERAL.stringify`. Also, this method saves extra bytes from the removing the quotes, I use to send data across the websocket pipe. Might not seem like a lot of bytes saved from shredding off the quotations, but if there is a lot of stuff being parsed, it will help.

Comment: When we push an object with stringify in the Redis list, it is saved as: "{...}". When we get the list from Redis, it is like this: ["{...}" ,"{...}"] but this is wrong and parse method does not work on it, it should be like this: [{...} ,{...}]